# get pixel color in Android emulator at x,y position

Tags: android, colors, android-emulator, pixel

I have the x,y position on the Android emulator screen.  Is there a way to find the pixel color at this specific x,y in the emulator screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, this is the code I use the get the RGB value of a specific pixel in any view.

```
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
view.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache();

int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);

int red = Color.red(pixel);
int green = Color.green(pixel);
int blue = Color.blue(pixel);

view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

The int values returned are your standard 0 - 255. You can modify this code and get a color from anywhere, providing you can turn it into a bitmap. And you can use the [Color API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html) to get an actual RGB value like this:

```
int rgb = Color.rgb(red, blue, green);
```

Comment: attention, this will give you only the pixel of your view - not the screen

Comment: Yes, as indicated in the first sentence of my the answer.

Comment: Yeah, but "any" view could indicate 3rd party views, too - which is not pissible without root. I am sure that you know that, but since OP asked for *screen* and not view, I found it usefull to add.

Comment: The only alternative answer, considering they mentioned an emulator. Is that you can take a screen shot of the host PC and use graphics software to pull out the pixel colours.